# Using pre-trained inception_resnet_v2 with Tensorflow

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been trying to use the pre-trained inception_resnet_v2 model released by Google. I am using their model definition(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py) and given checkpoint(http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.tar.gz) to load the model in tensorflow as below [Download a extract the checkpoint file and download sample images dog.jpg and panda.jpg to test this code]-

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim
from PIL import Image
from inception_resnet_v2 import *
import numpy as np

checkpoint_file = 'inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt'
sample_images = ['dog.jpg', 'panda.jpg']
#Load the model
sess = tf.Session()
arg_scope = inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()
with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
  logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(input_tensor, is_training=False)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
for image in sample_images:
  im = Image.open(image).resize((299,299))
  im = np.array(im)
  im = im.reshape(-1,299,299,3)
  predict_values, logit_values = sess.run([end_points['Predictions'], logits], feed_dict={input_tensor: im})
  print (np.max(predict_values), np.max(logit_values))
  print (np.argmax(predict_values), np.argmax(logit_values))
```

However, the results from this model code does not give the expected results (class no 918 is predicted irrespective of the input image). Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: Imagenet preprocessing required maybe ?

Comment: BTW, what is `input_tensor` for you code?

Comment: Instead of feeding image directly, try feeding this:  `im = np.array(im) - np.mean(np.array(im))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Inception networks expect the input image to have color channels scaled from [-1, 1]. As seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/preprocessing/inception_preprocessing.py#L237-L275).

You could either use the existing preprocessing, or in your example just scale the images yourself: `im = 2*(im/255.0)-1.0` before feeding them to the network.

Without scaling the input [0-255] is much larger than the network expects and the biases all work to very strongly predict category 918 (comic books).

Comment: @alemi, why use `im = 2*(im/255.0)-1.0` but not `im = im/255.0` for normlization?

Comment: Because zero is special, since the first operation is matrix multiplication, and black is fairly common.