# Tensorflow inception_v2_resnet inference

Tags: tensorflow, inference, resnet

With reference to this post:

[Using pre-trained inception_resnet_v2 with Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582703/using-pre-trained-inception-resnet-v2-with-tensorflow/40000088#40000088)

i am trying to use the inception_resnet_v2 model to get predictions of images also. Therefore i looked at the snippet and tried to get it running, but it says "input_tensor" is not defined. Is there anything missing in the code mentioned or can anyone get me some hint to get it running / how to define the input_tensor variable?

Here is the snippet again:

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim
from PIL import Image
from inception_resnet_v2 import *
import numpy as np

checkpoint_file = 'inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt'
sample_images = ['dog.jpg', 'panda.jpg']
#Load the model
sess = tf.Session()
arg_scope = inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()
with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
  logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(input_tensor, is_training=False)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
for image in sample_images:
  im = Image.open(image).resize((299,299))
  im = np.array(im)
  im = im.reshape(-1,299,299,3)
  predict_values, logit_values = sess.run([end_points['Predictions'],logits], feed_dict={input_tensor: im})
  print (np.max(predict_values), np.max(logit_values))
  print (np.argmax(predict_values), np.argmax(logit_values))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet appears to lack any definition for `input_tensor`. Looking at the [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/43dad80002d008f8c0d70718a9c88dce5a56eb21/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py#L94) of the `inception_resnet_v2()` function, the fact that the tensor is used in a `feed_dict`, and the fact that the size of your image is 299 x 299, you could define `input_tensor` as follows:

```
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 299, 299, 3])
```