# How can I make the inception-v3 model pre-trained from Imagenet (classify_image.py) in the Tensorflow tutorial importable as a module?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wonder how I can modify classify_image.py (from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition#usage_with_python_api) so that I can import it from another python script. I would basically like it to have the same functionality it already has, but instead of providing the image path and getting the response printed out in the terminal, I would like to give a function the image path and get the function to return the top 5 results with their probabilities.

I haven’t found a direct solution to this problem yet, but I realize my problem solving and search for previous answers are limited since I unfortunately haven’t learned the basics of Tensorflow yet.

Of course, if there is another pre-trained Tensorflow model that is just as good and meets my demands I would happily use that instead.

Regards,
Pontus

**UPDATE** Maybe I should clearify a little:

I don't want to train a model, just use a pre-trained one for image recognition, and in this case have an image recognition script that I could import as a module in another python application.

I have also tried with code from [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582703/using-pre-trained-inception-resnet-v2-with-tensorflow) but I got stuck there too, and in that case it includes a lot of manual installation where I might have failed in some step. The good thing with the [classify_image.py example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition#usage_with_python_api) is that I got it to work as intended to in the tutorial so I thought that the step from that to using it as a pluggable module shouldn't be that big.

What I have tried (with classify_image.py) is moving the lines beneath `if __name__ = '__main__'` to `main(_)` in order for them to get executed when I call them from another script but I am still having problems. I am mainly having problems with the `main(_)` function, that wants me to pass it an argument, and from searching around I figured `_` seems to be some kind of placeholder used when getting input from the cli. All the FLAGS stuff seems to be cli related too, which is what I want to move away from. I am also unsure whether the model weights etc get saved correctly for me to be able to use it from another script. Again, at this point I just want to play around with the image classifier and further on hopefully learn more about the machine learning behind it. Sorry for my lack of knowledge in the basics of this!

classify_image.py:

```
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================

"""Simple image classification with Inception.
Run image classification with Inception trained on ImageNet 2012 Challenge data
set.
This program creates a graph from a saved GraphDef protocol buffer,
and runs inference on an input JPEG image. It outputs human readable
strings of the top 5 predictions along with their probabilities.
Change the --image_file argument to any jpg image to compute a
classification of that image.
Please see the tutorial and website for a detailed description of how
to use this script to perform image recognition.
https://tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition/
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import os.path
import re
import sys
import tarfile

import numpy as np
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None

# pylint: disable=line-too-long
DATA_URL = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz'
# pylint: enable=line-too-long


class NodeLookup(object):
  """Converts integer node ID's to human readable labels."""

  def __init__(self,
               label_lookup_path=None,
               uid_lookup_path=None):
    if not label_lookup_path:
      label_lookup_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.model_dir, 'imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt')
    if not uid_lookup_path:
      uid_lookup_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.model_dir, 'imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt')
    self.node_lookup = self.load(label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path)

  def load(self, label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path):
    """Loads a human readable English name for each softmax node.
    Args:
      label_lookup_path: string UID to integer node ID.
      uid_lookup_path: string UID to human-readable string.
    Returns:
      dict from integer node ID to human-readable string.
    """
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(uid_lookup_path):
      tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', uid_lookup_path)
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(label_lookup_path):
      tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', label_lookup_path)

    # Loads mapping from string UID to human-readable string
    proto_as_ascii_lines = tf.gfile.GFile(uid_lookup_path).readlines()
    uid_to_human = {}
    p = re.compile(r'[n\d]*[ \S,]*')
    for line in proto_as_ascii_lines:
      parsed_items = p.findall(line)
      uid = parsed_items[0]
      human_string = parsed_items[2]
      uid_to_human[uid] = human_string

    # Loads mapping from string UID to integer node ID.
    node_id_to_uid = {}
    proto_as_ascii = tf.gfile.GFile(label_lookup_path).readlines()
    for line in proto_as_ascii:
      if line.startswith('  target_class:'):
        target_class = int(line.split(': ')[1])
      if line.startswith('  target_class_string:'):
        target_class_string = line.split(': ')[1]
        node_id_to_uid[target_class] = target_class_string[1:-2]

    # Loads the final mapping of integer node ID to human-readable string
    node_id_to_name = {}
    for key, val in node_id_to_uid.items():
      if val not in uid_to_human:
        tf.logging.fatal('Failed to locate: %s', val)
      name = uid_to_human[val]
      node_id_to_name[key] = name

    return node_id_to_name

  def id_to_string(self, node_id):
    if node_id not in self.node_lookup:
      return ''
    return self.node_lookup[node_id]


def create_graph():
  """Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
  # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
  with tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(
      FLAGS.model_dir, 'classify_image_graph_def.pb'), 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')


def run_inference_on_image(image):
  """Runs inference on an image.
  Args:
    image: Image file name.
  Returns:
    Nothing
  """
  if not tf.gfile.Exists(image):
    tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
  image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()

  # Creates graph from saved GraphDef.
  create_graph()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Some useful tensors:
    # 'softmax:0': A tensor containing the normalized prediction across
    #   1000 labels.
    # 'pool_3:0': A tensor containing the next-to-last layer containing 2048
    #   float description of the image.
    # 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': A tensor containing a string providing JPEG
    #   encoding of the image.
    # Runs the softmax tensor by feeding the image_data as input to the graph.
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
    predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

    # Creates node ID --> English string lookup.
    node_lookup = NodeLookup()

    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
    for node_id in top_k:
      human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
      score = predictions[node_id]
      print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))


def maybe_download_and_extract():
  """Download and extract model tar file."""
  dest_directory = FLAGS.model_dir
  if not os.path.exists(dest_directory):
    os.makedirs(dest_directory)
  filename = DATA_URL.split('/')[-1]
  filepath = os.path.join(dest_directory, filename)
  if not os.path.exists(filepath):
    def _progress(count, block_size, total_size):
      sys.stdout.write('\r>> Downloading %s %.1f%%' % (
          filename, float(count * block_size) / float(total_size) * 100.0))
      sys.stdout.flush()
    filepath, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(DATA_URL, filepath, _progress)
    print()
    statinfo = os.stat(filepath)
    print('Successfully downloaded', filename, statinfo.st_size, 'bytes.')
  tarfile.open(filepath, 'r:gz').extractall(dest_directory)


def main(_):
  maybe_download_and_extract()
  image = (FLAGS.image_file if FLAGS.image_file else
           os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'cropped_panda.jpg'))
  run_inference_on_image(image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  # classify_image_graph_def.pb:
  #   Binary representation of the GraphDef protocol buffer.
  # imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt:
  #   Map from synset ID to a human readable string.
  # imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt:
  #   Text representation of a protocol buffer mapping a label to synset ID.
  parser.add_argument(
      '--model_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/imagenet',
      help="""\
      Path to classify_image_graph_def.pb,
      imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt, and
      imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt.\
      """
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--image_file',
      type=str,
      default='',
      help='Absolute path to image file.'
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--num_top_predictions',
      type=int,
      default=5,
      help='Display this many predictions.'
  )
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to use the code from the SO article reffered to in the update in the original question. I modified the code with the additional `im = 2*(im/255.0)-1.0` from the answer of said SO question, some line to fix PIL on my computer plus a function to convert classes to human readable labels (found on github), link to that file below. I made it a callable function that takes a list of images as input and outputs a list of labels and predict values. If you'd like to use it, this is what you have to to:

1. Install the latest Tensorflow version (1.0 at the moment, which is needed).
2. `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models/`where you want the models.
3. Put [this checkpoint file](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.tar.gz) from the SO question I referred to earlier (needs to be extracted, of course) in the directory of your project.
4. Put [this text file](https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a) (the human readable labels) in the directory of your project.
5. Use this code from the SO question with some modifications from my side, put it in a .py file in your project:

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   slim = tf.contrib.slim
   import PIL as pillow
   from PIL import Image
   #import Image
   from inception_resnet_v2 import *
   import numpy as np

   with open('imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.txt','r') as inf:
       imagenet_classes = eval(inf.read())

   def get_human_readable(id):
       id = id - 1
       label = imagenet_classes[id]

       return label

   checkpoint_file = './inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt'

   #Load the model
   sess = tf.Session()
   arg_scope = inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()
   input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 299, 299, 3])  
   with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
       logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(input_tensor, is_training=False)
   saver = tf.train.Saver()
   saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)

   def classify_image(sample_images):
       classifications = []
       for image in sample_images:
           im = Image.open(image).resize((299,299))
           im = np.array(im)
           im = im.reshape(-1,299,299,3)
           im = 2*(im/255.0)-1.0
           predict_values, logit_values = sess.run([end_points['Predictions'], logits], feed_dict={input_tensor: im})
           #print (np.max(predict_values), np.max(logit_values))
           #print (np.argmax(predict_values), np.argmax(logit_values))
           label = get_human_readable(np.argmax(predict_values))
           predict_value = np.max(predict_values)
           classifications.append({"label":label, "predict_value":predict_value})

       return classifications
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1) First question is about how to return the predicted values. 
Following code snippet does predition on the given image:

```
    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
    for node_id in top_k:
      human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
      score = predictions[node_id]
      print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Instead of print you can save the result in some data structure and return. By default, 5 top predictions will be returned, if you would like to change this behavior set proper value to `--num_top_predictions`.

2) **Regarding Model**:
There are two parts to it-

1. You need to have quality dataset as Imagenet is.
2. Assuming if you have such quality dataset, the infrastructure to train inception would require very powerful GPUs. Lot of time too.

but if you still want to train your system with your own dataset, I would say initially train with imagenet and later train the final layer(tensor name is '**final_result**') with your own dataset. Please find this [tutorial](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/).

Comment: Thanks Milind! But I am having problems long before replacing the print statement with a return. I'll update my question now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just replace `[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:]` with `[-5:]`

Then replace other FLAG with directory and file the image sit on.