# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 357604 into shape (299,299,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, reshape

> Code from
>   [How can I make the inception-v3 model pre-trained from Imagenet (classify_image.py) in the Tensorflow tutorial importable as a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345015/how-can-i-make-the-inception-v3-model-pre-trained-from-imagenet-classify-image)

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim
import PIL as pillow
from PIL import Image
#import Image
from inception_resnet_v2 import *
import numpy as np

with open('imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.txt','r') as inf:
    imagenet_classes = eval(inf.read())

def get_human_readable(id):
    id = id - 1
    label = imagenet_classes[id]

    return label

checkpoint_file = './inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt'

#Load the model
sess = tf.Session()
arg_scope = inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 299, 299, 3])  
with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
    logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(input_tensor, is_training=False)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)

def classify_image(sample_images):
    classifications = []
    for image in sample_images:
        im = Image.open(image).resize((299,299))
        im = np.array(im)
        im = im.reshape(-1,299,299,3)
        im = 2*(im/255.0)-1.0
        predict_values, logit_values = sess.run([end_points['Predictions'], logits], feed_dict={input_tensor: im})
        #print (np.max(predict_values), np.max(logit_values))
        #print (np.argmax(predict_values), np.argmax(logit_values))
        label = get_human_readable(np.argmax(predict_values))
        predict_value = np.max(predict_values)
        classifications.append({"label":label, "predict_value":predict_value})

    return classifications
```

I get the following error when running some images:

```
"ValueError: can not reshape array of size 357604 into shape (299,299.3)"
```

I do not understand where it comes from. Indeed, the image is resized (299, 299) before being reshape.
I do not understand because most of my images work, except a few ...

Did you have any idea about the cause of this problem?

Thank you in advance :)

**SOLUTION**:

I converted my image to RGB using the code provided here: [Convert RGBA PNG to RGB with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil)

Now everything works perfectly :)
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `299 x 299 x 4 = 357604`. It appears that some of the images that do not work have 4 channels per pixel (RGBA perhaps) instead of 3 channels per pixel (just RGB, not A).

Comment: You're most likely right, thanks :) But if I change the code to put a 4, I get this error : ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 299, 299, 4) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 299, 299, 3)'

Comment: Thank you for giving me the right way, I edited my message :)

Comment: Same problem here. Can you tell me which method you choose in the referred link to convert your files? I don't know much about images, alpha channel and related concepts. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can easily convert **RGBA((299,299,4) shape)** to **RGB(299,299,3)** by using PIL convert

```
im = im.convert('RGB')
```